# Int decimal count in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, count, int, decimal

I need to know whatever an int64_t has decimals, and how many. This should be placed in if-else-statement. I tried this code, but it causes the app to crash.

```
        NSNumber *numValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:testAnswer];
        NSString *string = [numValue stringValue];
        NSArray *stringComps = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        int64_t numberOfDecimalPlaces = [[stringComps objectAtIndex:1] length];
        if (numberOfDecimalPlaces == 0) {
            [self doSomething];
            } else {
            [self doSomethingElse];
            }
```

Comment: there is only one decimal anywhere ... wat is ur issue specifically ?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: I use arc4Random() to generate two random int64_t. Then, I check that the first random int is bigger than the second. Next, I divide them and create the testAnswer int. Now I need to check if the testAnswer has decimals and how many. If it has too many, I'll regenerate the random ints.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense; you are creating the `NSNumber` object from an `int` so it will never have decimal places, as an `int` cannot store them.  The reason your code is crashing is that it assumes that the array of components is always at least 2 elements long (as you use `objectAtIndex:1`).

This is better, though still not that good:

```
NSString *answer = ...;   // From somewhere
NSArray *stringComps = [answer componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([stringComps count] == 0) {
    [self doSomething];
} else if [stringComps count] == 1) {
    [self doSomethingElse];
} else {
    // Error! More than one period entered
}
```

This still isn't a very good test as it only tests if a period (`.`) has been entered, not a valid number.

Comment: if ([stringComps length] == 0) already gives me an error that no visible @interface for "NSArray" declares the selector "length"

Comment: @imas145 Appologies; it's `count`, not `length`.